# What is the difference between the two snippets?

Tags: c++, c++11, valarray

I need some explanation for `[](int x){return x=x+5;}`. What does `[] (int x)` mean?

I ran the `varr.apply(incelemby5)`
where `incelemby5` increases array elements by 5. Got the same results

```
varr1 = varr.apply([](int x){return x=x+5;});

int incelemby5(int x) {
    return x+5;
}
```

Comment: That's a "lambda", a way to define and pass a function to an object that will call it.

Comment: Helpful reading: [What is a lambda expression in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a lambda expression in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++11 introduces Lambda expression. You can create a function object(which has `operator()`) immediately. Each lambda has a unique type name so that compiler can optimize it easier than the function pointer which is the same type name for the same signature.

BTW, these two samples will make the same effects because `x` which is 1st argument of the lambda is not an lvalue reference.

```cpp
varr1 = varr.apply([](int x){return x=x+5;});
```

```cpp
varr1 = varr.apply([](int x){return x+5;});
```